# If noise is your signal, what is your noise?

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, gaussian, stochastic

Consider the following contrived situation. Imagine a Gaussian white noise process $x[t]$, with bandwidth $Δf$, with PSD equal to some quantity $A$ which you would like to measure.

So the way to measure this seems to measure the variance of the process $x[t]$, which by Parseval's theorem will be $AΔf$.

So you measure points with some frequency $f_m$, probably $2Δf$. And at a lower rate, say $f_v$, you compute the variance of the preceding block of $f_m/f_v$ points and take that to be a measurement. What will the noise/variance be in this measurement of the variance of $x[t]$? How can I approach this question?

Comment: this is the kinda question that people doing watermarking ask.  is that what you're doing?

Comment: Robert, I posted this as a guest but have lost my cookie and appear to have already had an account; this account does not have enough reputation to comment and I do not know a way to get the guest cookie back. This is actually an infrared detector application.

Comment: @BrianP : Please merge your accounts: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a derivation over on the math.SE site that might be useful.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/72978/5965)

Provided your data is Gaussian with variance $\sigma^2$.

If you use the unbiased estimator of the population variance:
$$
S^2_{N-1} = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (x[n]- \bar{x})^2
$$
where $N$ is the number of points in your batch and $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean, then the variance of this estimate will be:
$$
\frac{2 \sigma^4}{N-1}
$$

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Can anything be said about the PSD of the new "variance of $x[t]$" signal?

Comment: Provided there are no overlapping entries in each calculation of the variance estimate, I expect all the estimates will be uncorrelated from each other... so the sequence of variance estimates will be white, so the PSD should be a constant.

Comment: Thanks. And, one more question: suppose the noise were not white or $x[t]$ were not Gaussian. Am I correct that this would still approximately hold for $f_m/f_v \gg 1$, by the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: Well, the original variance estimate would need to be revised, as it assumes whiteness. And then you'd have to see how that coloration carried through.

Answer (score 0):

Is SNR really the quantity that you desire? In your situation, I would assume you are more interested in how accurately you can measure $A$. Why don't you simply take, let's say, 100 measurements, and compute the mean and standard deviation of all $A_i$ from your this data? If you need to compare different measurement strategies, you could then use a "temporal SNR" given by the mean and standard deviation of $A$ as $SNR_t = \frac{\bar{A}}{\sigma_A}$.

Comment: Right, but I'm interested in a theoretical derivation of $\sigma_A$ to compare with such an empirical measurement.

Comment: I understand. If this is just an empirical measure... no, I wouldn't say that. Compare it to medical imaging (specifically MRI): The SNR derivation there from ROIs within signal and noise areas is just an easy substitute for doing the measurement a few hundred times and calculating the SNR pixel-wise by this formula. It is also known in fMRI as *temporal SNR* (however, imho this is a bit doubtful there). Maybe you can find an appropriate theoretical framework with this *temporal* approach. If your measurement itself does not exhibit any noise, it might be hard to link it to common formula.